# MYSQL group_concat equivalent in Sybase ASE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sap-ase

Is there a equivalent function in Sybase ASE to the group_concat of MYSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

you have to create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet create a cursor that processes one row at a time which could go into a stored procedure. The cursor query is assumed to sort the data via the order by clause and then concatenates the data via an expression like group_concat = group_concat + field.

You have the power!

Good SQL, good night.

Answer (score 1):

This query will concat the rows in the "column_to_concat" column, you can change the space separator character with commas, slash, etc. In this case i choose space because with trim i can get rid off the spaces at the start and end of the output.

```
SELECT column_to_concat
INTO #table_temp
FROM table

DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100)

UPDATE #table_temp
SET @data = @data + ' ' + column_to_concat

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@data))

DROP TABLE #table_temp
```

Comment: Additional explanation would improve your answer.

Comment: There is the additional explanation :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIST function:

```
SELECT continent,
LIST (country, ',') as countries_in_continent
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
```