# SQL SELECT DISTINCT but combine results from another table

Tags: php, sql, select, odbc, sybase

I'm not even sure what to search for so forgive me if this is already covered somewhere.

I have a SELECT statement that pulls data from several tables.  As expected if I run this query I get a record for each record in the second table, like this.

```
|ID     |Name     |Assets
 ------------------------------------
|1      |Bob      |Car
|1      |Bob      |Bicycle
|1      |Bob      |House
|2      |Jane     |Car
|2      |Jane     |House
|3      |Peter    |Boat
|3      |Peter    |Car
|3      |Peter    |Motorcycle
```

What I want is something like this:

```
|ID     |Name     |Assets
 ------------------------------------
|1      |Bob      |Car,Bicycle,House
|2      |Jane     |Car,House
|3      |Peter    |Boat,Car,Motorcycle
```

I have been able to achieve this using PHP by simply hitting the database a second time for each record I get from the first table, but this has made my page slow as it's hitting the database some 40-60 times per page refresh.

Query 1:

```
SELECT ID,Name FROM People
```

Then Query 2 within a while loop:

```
<?php
while($owner_row=odbc_fetch_array($query1) {
$assets = odbc_exec($conn,"SELECT Asset FROM Assets WHERE Owner='$owner_row[Name]'");
$asset_array = odbc_fetch_array($assets);
$asset_string = implode(",",$asset_array);
}
```

I can then combine the Asset results from each owner into a string and display them as I like.

Is there a way to achieve this in a single query so that I only hit the database once and somehow combine those assets into a single value within the query itself?

Comment: What RDMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm accessing a SyBase database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491566/how-to-get-list-of-values-in-group-by-clause

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what database you are hitting, but if you are using mySQL, there is a lovely function that does this called group_concat which works like this:

```
select 
    a.ID, 
    a.Name, 
    group_concat(b.Asset) as assetGroup 
from 
    people a
        join Assets b
            on a.ID=b.Owner 
group by 
    a.ID, 
    a.Name
```

Which would output EXACTLY:

```
|ID     |Name     |Assets
 ------------------------------------
|1      |Bob      |Car,Bicycle,House
|2      |Jane     |Car,House
|3      |Peter    |Boat,Car,Motorcycle
```

Edit: I am assuming that each record in the table people has at least one matching record in the Assets table - if not, use an outer join instead on the query.

Edit: I am not familiar with SyBase, but a quick search for a related function gave me bad news: [MYSQL group_concat equivalent in Sybase ASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230712/mysql-group-concat-equivalent-in-sybase-ase) there isn't a function like this in SyBase, you will have to write a stored procedure to get the results, but it indicates that you can still do this (albeit in a much more difficult manner) directly on the database.

If you don't want to write a stored procedure, you can still join the tables in the query, and then simply return many rows per ID into PHP and simply loop through them along the lines of:

```
$currentID=0;
$userAssets=array();
while($row=$AnotherRowFromTheDatabase)
{
    if($row['ID']==$currentID)
    {
        $userAssets[]=$row['Asset'];
    }
    else
    {
        $currentID=$row['ID'];
        // More stuff to move the array previously
        // and start a new Assets Array
    }
}
```

Comment: He's actually grabbing data from two tables

Comment: @DavidFaber If he is still hitting a mysql, he can use the function in a multi-table query perfectly well. I have however updated the query to work with the table structure he describes.

Comment: Hi Guys,  As above.  It's Sybase via an ODBC connection.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Fluffeh.  I might just stick to my nice slow PHP solution in that case.  Thanks for trying.  :)

Comment: @Barbs I gave you a (probably) much quicker solution than making 40-60 queries against the database in my edit just now.

Comment: @Barbs, Fluffeh is right.You should try to use the built in function of sybase for this which will be more efficient. The equivalent of Group_Concat (found in MySql) is LIST function found in Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sybase [LIST](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-sasarc/awg0603e/dbrfen6/@ebt-link;pt=31454?target=%25N%15_37949_START_RESTART_N%25) function here.

e.g.

```
SELECT ID,NAME,LIST(ASSETS)
FROM PEOPLE
GROUP BY ID,NAME
```

Comment: Hi Niladri,  with a fairly simple query I get "Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [DataDirect][ODBC Sybase Wire Protocol driver][SQL Server]Function 'LIST' not found." so there may be a version issue with the database I'm accessing.  I'm going to try some other methods (altering design etc to handle the data in a different way) and will put this method to sleep for now.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below SQL:

```
declare @tempUser  Table
(
ID int,
Name nvarchar(250),
AssetNAme nvarchar(250)
)
Insert into @tempUser values(1,'Bob','Car')
Insert into @tempUser values(1,'Bob','Bicycle')
Insert into @tempUser values(1,'Bob','House')
Insert into @tempUser values(2,'Jane','Car')
Insert into @tempUser values(2,'Jane','House')
Insert into @tempUser values(3,'Peter','Boat')
Insert into @tempUser values(3,'Peter','Car')
Insert into @tempUser values(3,'Peter','MotorCycle')


select  tt.ID,tt.Name,(select ITT.AssetNAme + ', ' as 'data()'  from @tempUser as ITT 
where ITT.ID =tt.ID for xml path('')) from @tempUser  as tt group by tt.ID,tt.Name
```

Comment: it's in sybase and not sql server