# Combine two rows into one rows in Sybase ASE

Tags: select, sybase, ase

I have a resultset as below:

```
id fname  lname
11 Tom   Jerry
11 Kim   Harry
```

Output I expected as below:

```
id fname     lname
11 Tom,Kim   Jerry,Harry
```

Appreciate your help.
thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL group\_concat equivalent in Sybase ASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230712/mysql-group-concat-equivalent-in-sybase-ase)

Comment: ASE does not have anything equivalent to `list()` or `group_concat()` so you're going to be left with some sort of procedural method (eg, stored procedure, cursor, user-defined function), and even then you'll need to weigh a) hardcoding the references for a specific table and columns vs b) writing a generic process to handle any table/column references (likely requiring ASE 16 where you have access to table variables)